# Why does my Mat-stepper doesn't show immediately when the page is loaded?

Tags: angular, mat-stepper, ngx-editor

I am encountering a very weird issue . I am developing a website with angular 13.0.2 and I am creating a form using mat-stepper (and ngx-editor , I mention it in case it's the problem).When the page loads everything shows perfectly except for the mat-stepper. I have to click on the screen for it to show. I must admit I have quite a lot of elements in my forms but I don't know if it's because of that. What may be the problem here?

Thanks.

PS:Here's the entire html code since there's no backend yet.

```
<div class="formprojets col-lg-15">
<h2>Nouvelle charte de projet</h2>
<mat-stepper #stepper>
    <mat-step [stepControl]="groupe1" errorMessage="Name is required.">
        <form [formGroup]="groupe1">
            <div class="desczone">
                <h6>DESCRIPTION GENERALE SYNTHETIQUE DU PROJET</h6>
                <p>Comment se présente le contexte de l’élaboration du projet ?</p>
                <p>De quoi parle le projet généralement ?</p>
                <ng-template matStepLabel>Descritpion - Acceptation</ng-template>
                <div class="NgxEditor__Wrapper">
                    <ngx-editor-menu [editor]="editor" [toolbar]="toolbar"> </ngx-editor-menu>
                    <ngx-editor formControlName="grp1" [editor]="editor" [ngModel]="desc" [disabled]="false"
                        [placeholder]="'Type here...'">
                    </ngx-editor>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h6>ACCEPTATION DU PROJET:</h6>
                <p>Quels sont les conventions entre les parties prenantes ?</p>
                <p>Que contient ces conventions ?</p>
                <div class="NgxEditor__Wrapper">
                    <ngx-editor-menu [editor]="editor2" [toolbar]="toolbar"> </ngx-editor-menu>
                    <ngx-editor formControlName="grp1_2" [editor]="editor2" [ngModel]="accept" [disabled]="false"
                        [placeholder]="'Type here...'">
                    </ngx-editor>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step [stepControl]="groupe2" errorMessage="Tous les champs doivent être remplis">
        <form [formGroup]="groupe2">
            <div class="desczone">
                <h6>OBJECTIFS ET CONTENU DU PROGRAMME</h6>
                <p>Présentation des objectifs générales du projet par contenu</p>
                <ng-template matStepLabel>Objectifs - Livrables</ng-template>
                <div class="NgxEditor__Wrapper">
                    <ngx-editor-menu [editor]="editor3" [toolbar]="toolbar"> </ngx-editor-menu>
                    <ngx-editor formControlName="grp2_1" [editor]="editor3" [disabled]="false"
                        [placeholder]="'Type here...'">
                    </ngx-editor>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="desczone">
                <h6>LIVRABLES MAJEURES DU PROJET</h6>
                <p>Quels sont les livrables majeurs représentant les étapes importants conduisant à l’atteinte des
                    objectifs du projet ?</p>
                <div class="NgxEditor__Wrapper">
                    <ngx-editor-menu [editor]="editor4" [toolbar]="toolbar"> </ngx-editor-menu>
                    <ngx-editor formControlName="grp2_2" [editor]="editor4" [disabled]="false"
                        [placeholder]="'Type here...'">
                    </ngx-editor>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step [stepControl]="groupe3" errorMessage="Address is required.">
        <form [formGroup]="groupe3">
            <div class="desczone">
                <h6>DOMAINE D’APPLICATION DU PROJET </h6>
                <p>Quels sont les limites du projet ?</p>
                <ng-template matStepLabel>Domaine d'application - Parties prenantes</ng-template>
                <div class="NgxEditor__Wrapper">
                    <ngx-editor-menu [editor]="editor5" [toolbar]="toolbar"> </ngx-editor-menu>
                    <ngx-editor formControlName="grp3_1" [editor]="editor5" [disabled]="false"
                        [placeholder]="'Type here...'">
                    </ngx-editor>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <h6>LISTE DES PARTIES PRENANTES DU PROJET</h6>
                    <p>Quels sont les limites du projet ?</p>
                    <div style="margin-top: 1%;">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="form-input">
                            <mat-label>Rôle</mat-label>
                            <input matInput type="text" placeholder="" [(ngModel)]="role"
                                [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" required>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="form-input">
                            <mat-label>Dénomination</mat-label>
                            <input matInput type="text" placeholder="" [(ngModel)]="denomination"
                                [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" required>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                    <button (click)="add_liste()" mat-raised-button class="add">Ajouter</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="tablePart">
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="n°">
                            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> N° </th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.id}}</td>
                        </ng-container>
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="role">
                            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Rôle </th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.role}}</td>
                        </ng-container>
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="denomination">
                            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Dénomination </th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.denomination}}</td>
                        </ng-container>
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
                            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Action </th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4 actionrow">
                                        <button mat-mini-fab aria-label="Ajouter un projet" class="delete">
                                            <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4 actionrow">
                                        <button mat-mini-fab aria-label="Ajouter un projet" class="edit">
                                            <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </ng-container>
                        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
                        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
                        <!-- Row shown when there is no matching data. -->
                        <tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow>
                            <td class="mat-cell" colspan="4">No data matching the filter</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step [stepControl]="groupe4" errorMessage="Address is required.">
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Stratégie - Budget</ng-template>
        <form [formGroup]="groupe4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 desczone">
                    <h6>STRATEGIE DE MISE EN ŒUVRE</h6>
                    <p>Quels sont les stratégies générales pour mettre en œuvre le projet ?</p>

                    <div style="margin-top: 1%;">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="form-input">
                            <mat-label>Partie Prenante</mat-label>
                            <input matInput type="text" placeholder="" [(ngModel)]="partie_prenante"
                                [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" required>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                            <mat-label>Hierarchie</mat-label>
                            <mat-select [(ngModel)]="hierarchie">
                                <mat-option value="one">1</mat-option>
                                <mat-option value="two">2</mat-option>
                            </mat-select>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                    <button (click)="add_strat()" mat-raised-button class="add">Ajouter</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 desczone">
                    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSourceStrat" matSort class="tablePart">
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="n°">
                            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> N° </th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.nom}}</td>
                        </ng-container>
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="hierarchie">
                            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Hiérarchie </th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.logo}}</td>
                        </ng-container>
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="partieprenante">
                            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Partie Prenante </th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.logo}}</td>
                        </ng-container>
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
                            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Action </th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4 actionrow">
                                        <button mat-mini-fab aria-label="Ajouter un projet" class="delete">
                                            <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4 actionrow">
                                        <button mat-mini-fab aria-label="Ajouter un projet" class="delete">
                                            <mat-icon>Edit</mat-icon>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </ng-container>
                        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumnsStrat"></tr>
                        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumnsStrat;"></tr>
                        <!-- Row shown when there is no matching data. -->
                        <tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow>
                            <td class="mat-cell" colspan="4">No data matching the filter</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 desczone">
                    <h6>BUDGET PREVISIONNEL DU PROJET</h6>
                    <p>A combien se chiffre le montant prévisionnel par contenu du projet ?</p>
                    <div style="margin-top: 1%;">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="form-input">
                            <mat-label>Désignation</mat-label>
                            <input matInput type="text" placeholder="" [(ngModel)]="designation"
                                [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" required>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="form-input">
                            <mat-label>Montant</mat-label>
                            <input matInput type="text" placeholder="" [(ngModel)]="montant"
                                [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" required>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                            <mat-label>Devise</mat-label>
                            <mat-select [(ngModel)]="devise">
                                <mat-option value="one">EUR</mat-option>
                                <mat-option value="two">AR</mat-option>
                            </mat-select>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                    <button (click)="add_budget()" mat-raised-button class="add">Ajouter</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 desczone">
                    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSourceBudget" matSort class="tablePart">
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="designation">
                            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Désignation</th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.nom}}</td>
                        </ng-container>
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="montant">
                            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Montant</th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.logo}}</td>
                        </ng-container>
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
                            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Action </th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4 actionrow">
                                        <button mat-mini-fab aria-label="Ajouter un projet" class="delete">
                                            <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4 actionrow">
                                        <button mat-mini-fab aria-label="Ajouter un projet" class="delete">
                                            <mat-icon>Edit</mat-icon>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </ng-container>

                        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumnsBudget"></tr>
                        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumnsBudget;"></tr>
                        <!-- Row shown when there is no matching data. -->
                        <tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow>
                            <td class="mat-cell" colspan="4">No data matching the filter</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 5%;">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <p style="font-weight:bold;">Total</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            ###
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step [stepControl]="groupe5" errorMessage="Address is required.">
        <form [formGroup]="groupe5">
            <ng-template matStepLabel>Exigeances - Risques</ng-template>
            <div class="desczone">
                <h6>LISTE DES EXIGENCES RELATIVES AU PROGRAMME</h6>
                <p>Quel sont les exigences relatives à la passation des marchés au niveau international et national
                    ?</p>
                <div class="editorzone">
                    <p class="titleeditor"> International</p>
                    <div class="NgxEditor__Wrapper">
                        <ngx-editor-menu [editor]="editor6" [toolbar]="toolbar"> </ngx-editor-menu>
                        <ngx-editor formControlName="grp5_1" [editor]="editor6"
                            [disabled]="false" [placeholder]="'Type here...'">
                        </ngx-editor>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="editorzone"> 
                    <p class="titleeditor"> National</p>
                    <div class="NgxEditor__Wrapper">
                        <ngx-editor-menu [editor]="editor7" [toolbar]="toolbar"> </ngx-editor-menu>
                        <ngx-editor formControlName="grp5_2" [editor]="editor7"
                            [disabled]="false" [placeholder]="'Type here...'">
                        </ngx-editor>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 desczone">
                    <h6>RISQUES DU PROJET</h6>
                    <p>Comment seront gérés les risques du projet ?</p>
                    <div style="margin-top: 1%;">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="form-input">
                            <mat-label>Risques et enjeux</mat-label>
                            <input matInput type="text" placeholder="" [(ngModel)]="enjeux"
                                [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" required>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="form-input">
                            <mat-label>Stratégie</mat-label>
                            <input matInput type="text" placeholder="" [(ngModel)]="strategie"
                                [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" required>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="form-input">
                            <mat-label>Actions de réponses</mat-label>
                            <input matInput type="text" placeholder="" [(ngModel)]="actionreponse"
                                [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" required>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="form-input">
                            <mat-label>Surveillance et mesurage</mat-label>
                            <input matInput type="text" placeholder="" [(ngModel)]="mesurage"
                                [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" required>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                    <button (click)="add_risques()" mat-raised-button class="add">Ajouter</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 desczone">
                    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSourceRisques" matSort class="tablePart">
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="risques">
                            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Risques et enjeux négatifs</th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.nom}}</td>
                        </ng-container>
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="strategie">
                            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Stratégie</th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.logo}}</td>
                        </ng-container>
                          <ng-container matColumnDef="actionsrep">
                            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Actions et réponses</th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.logo}}</td>
                        </ng-container>
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="surveillance">
                            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Surveillance et mesurage</th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.logo}}</td>
                        </ng-container>
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
                            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Action </th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4 actionrow">
                                        <button mat-mini-fab aria-label="Ajouter un projet" class="delete">
                                            <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4 actionrow">
                                        <button mat-mini-fab aria-label="Ajouter un projet" class="delete">
                                            <mat-icon>Edit</mat-icon>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </ng-container>
                        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumnsRisques"></tr>
                        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumnsRisques;"></tr>
                        <!-- Row shown when there is no matching data. -->
                        <tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow>
                            <td class="mat-cell" colspan="4">No data matching the filter</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step>
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Done</ng-template>
        <p>Vous avez terminé</p>
        <div>
            <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Retour</button>
            <button mat-button (click)="stepper.reset()">Réinitialiser</button>
            <button mat-button class="add" (click)="submit()">Valider</button>

        </div>
    </mat-step>
</mat-stepper>
```

Comment: Your problem is most likely in your code, so you need to show it. Please provide a [mcve], thanks!

Comment: Sure, sorry for the delay . I'll post my code down below.

Comment: I edited my post and added the code.